# Приклади використання слова "панівка" та "сунія"

Tags: переклад, вживання-слів

Шукаючи перекладів до рос. слова *"противень"* натрапив на [сторінку у «Словопедії»](http://lang.slovopedia.org.ua/11/53407/180864.html).

Серед можливих перекладів є *"сунія"* та *"панівка"*. Пошук в Ґуґлі не дає гарних прикладів для *"сунія"* та лише коротке визначення для *"панівка"*.

Підкажіть доречні приклади використання цих слів, будь ласка.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Те, що Ви цитуєте — словник **1924–1933 років**. Не дивно, що деякі зі слів, згаданих там, частково вийшли з ужитку. Сучасні словники «панівку» та «сунію», наскільки я знаю, не фіксують.

Сучасний еквівалент російського слова «противень» — **де́ко**:

- Відмінювання [в «Словниках України on-line» УМІФ (2006)](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE):

  > **де́ко** — іменник середнього роду:
  >   н. в. — де́ко (мн. — де́ка);
  >   р. в. — де́ка (мн. — дек);
  >   д. в. — де́ку, де́кові (мн. — де́кам);
  >   з. в. — де́ко (мн. — де́ка);
  >   о. в. — де́ком (мн. — де́ками);
  >   м. в. — де́ку (мн. — де́ках);
  >   к. в. — де́ко (мн. — де́ка).
- Визначання [в «Словнику української мови» (2010–…)](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=21395&page=725):

  > **ДЕ́КО**, а, *с.* Металевий лист, перев. із загнутими краями, для випікання, смаження.
  >
  > > *На засмалених деках височіли два окороки, під стелею звисала рожева шинка й домашні ковбаси* <sub>(В. Кучер)</sub>;
  > >     *Мені дух забило від погляду на припік: бабині руки чаклували над струдлями на декові, <…> пахучою засмагою мастили пироги*
  > >     <sub>(Є. Пашковський)</sub>.
- Стаття [в українській Вікіпедії](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE):

  > **Де́ко** — посудина, що має дно з тонкого металевого, скляного чи керамічного листа із загнутими краями та невисоким бортиком, для смаження та випікання їжі; форма для випікання. Інші назви — *дечка*, *лист* (для випікання), *листик*.

Також є гіперонім: **лист**.

Comment: Ось у цьомому [цікавому обговоренні](https://forum.durdom.in.ua/viewtopic.php?p=2953140) є ще з десяток варіянтів назви того предмета.

Comment: @YellowSky, дуже цікаво. Ще [трішки прикладів є тут](http://ukr.segodnya.ua/life/stories/trudnosti-perevoda-s-ukrainskogo-na-ukrainskiy-britvanka-rondil-i-fandel-617332.html).

Comment: Дякую за таку розширену відповідь. В більшості випадків дійсно цікавить переклад, тож відповідь (а особливо додаткові варіянти) дуже доречна. Проте де можна таки подивитись на приклади використання саме "сунія" та "панівка". Можливо в них є інші красномовні синоніми окрім "деко" ?

Comment: @ColdLearning, якщо чесно, не думаю, що десь можна подивитись на приклади використання. Це схоже на рідкі діалектні слова, що майже не застосовуються на письмі. Посилання на інші (також діалектні і рідкі) синоніми наводив Yellow Sky і я в коментарях вище.

Answer (score 6):

- «Сунія». Інтернет такого слова майже не знає — знаходить [всього 125 результатів](//www.google.com/search?q=%22%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%8F%22+OR+%22%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%97%22+OR+%22%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%8E%22+OR+%22%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%94%D1%8E%22+OR+%22%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9%22+OR+%22%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%8F%D0%BC%22+OR+%22%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8%22+OR+%22%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%8F%D1%85%22&num=100&start=100), з них переважна більшість: одруки, результати неправильного розпізнавання, власні назви, іншомовні слова або цитування тієї самої словникової статті. Але таки є:

  - Серіал «The Walking Dead», сезон 5, серія 13 «Forget» [в перекладі UATeam](http://uateam.tv/the-walking-dead/388) («І мертві підуть» і «Забудь» відповідно), 33:12:

    > *[Сем:]* Що ти тут робиш?
    >   *[Керол Пелетьє:]* А ти що тут робиш?
    >   *[Сем:]* Я пішов за тобою. Сподівався, що ти приготуєш ще печеннячок, а ти пішла сюди.
    >   *[Керол Пелетьє:]* Я можу приготувати ще. Можу цілу **сунію** тобі зробити. Хочеш?
  - Рецензії на книгу Горана Петровича «Острів та інші видіння»:

    - [Рецензія Андрія Гуренка](http://vsiknygy.net.ua/shcho_pochytaty/review/94/):

      > За Петровичем, «світ був округлою **сунією**» (*залізна бляшанка для випічки хліба*), яка «оточена по краях розповіддю».
    - [Рецензія Євгенії Гай](//krytyka.com/ua/reviews/ostriv-ta-inshi-vydinnya):

      > Сни тут вагоміші за «яву», а леґенди існують у паралельному до сьогодення вимірі, адже «світ є округлою **сунією**, що обрамлена розповіддю».
  - [Зоряна Гук «Постмодерністська інтерпретація міфу про Геро і Леандра у романі Мілорада Павича „Внутрішня сторона вітру“»](http://www.rastko.rs/rastko/delo/13614):

    > Наприкінці цієї частини роману М. Павич створює перспективу прострово-часової картографії за допомогою запису на мідній гравюрі круглої сунії: «... на зовнішній стороні круглої сунії була намальована мапа світу, неба і землі, мапа всього видимого і невидимого простору...».
- «Панівка» («пановка»). Інна Царалунга в статті [«Назви посуду в українських актових книгах кінця ХVІ – початку ХVІІ століття»](http://eprints.zu.edu.ua/18284/1/%D0%A6%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0_30.pdf) пише:

  > Як різновид (або синонім) сковороди визначаємо слово *панεвъка*: панεвокъ двѣ  (ДМВН, 1650, 193), похідне від *панва* «сковорода», запозиченого від польськ. *panew* «сковорода» (ЕСУМ, IV, 274). Номен *пановъ* «сковорода», ХІІІ ст., міститься у праці І. Срезневського (Срезневський, ІІ, 876). У перекладних словниках пізніших століть *пановка/панівка* – «каструля» (Желехівський, ІІ, 599), *панівка* «[частина рушниці; заглиблення у механізмі млина; деко](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/36576-panivka.html)» (Грінченко, ІІІ, 92). У сучасному літературному мовленні збереглося лише одне із значень: *панівка* «[частина затвора у пістолетів і рушниць](http://sum.in.ua/s/panivka)» (СУМ, VI, 45). В усному регіональному мовленні вживається зрідка: *пановка* «сковорода; каструля; ринка» (Верхратський, 446), *панівки*, мн. «частина млина, куди сиплеться чисте зерно». (Шило, 193).

  Тому не дивно, що пошук в Інтернеті наразі знаходить *[панівку](//www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%22+OR+%22%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8%22+OR+%22%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%86%D1%96%22+OR+%22%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D1%83%22+OR+%22%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%8E%22+OR+%22%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA%22+OR+%22%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%22+OR+%22%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%22+OR+%22%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85%22)* (або *[пановку](//www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%22+OR+%22%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8%22+OR+%22%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%86%D0%BE%22+OR+%22%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D1%83%22+OR+%22%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%8E%22+OR+%22%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA%22+OR+%22%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%22+OR+%22%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%22+OR+%22%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85%22)*) лише в сучасному значенні («частина затвора»), або як іншомовне слово чи власну назву.

Comment: величезне дяюку за додаткову розширену відповідь. Якраз те, що шукав